# Can't go anywhere from user edit page after login

Tags: 7, users, redirection

Having an issue with a certain user that is not reflected on other users, when this particular user is logging in he isn't redirected to homepage or to

> admin/dashboard

but to

> user/edit

page, and from there can't go anywhere, accessing any links lead to the same ***user/edit*** page and the url look like this example:

> /user/80/edit/account?destination=node

I'm getting the server response (again for this particular user)

> 302: moved temporarily

Is that a server issue? If yes, why another users don't have this issue?

Comment: Is it only that user that is a problem? Maybe it's an error in your .htaccess file.

Comment: 1) Check the user's role
2) Check the permissions attached to that role - can they access administratove pages?

Comment: How does this user login?

Comment: @macjules User have the role of administrator (Full permissions).

Comment: @Jdrupal I checked .htaccess file everything looks right i think.